# Razor: One or more compilation references are missing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

I am facing an issue with a ViewModel in a razor page whereby the ViewModels namespace is not being recognised and is causing the following error:

[image]

If I change the namespace of the ViewModel to App.Models or to App.Models.AccountViewModel (The other ViewModel namespace) then the above error is not triggered and the page loads and operates correctly.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

ViewModel:

```
namespace App.Models.DocumentViewModels 
{
    public class UploadDocumentViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Document Type")]
        public string DocumentType { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Document Number")]
        public string DocumentNumber { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Document Expiry")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime DocumentExpiry { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Shared Status")]
        public bool SharedStatus { get; set; } = false;
    }
}
```

RazorPage:

```
@model UploadDocumentViewModel

    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Upload Document";
    }

    <h2>@ViewData["Title"]</h2>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <form asp-route-returnUrl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" method="post">
                <h4>Upload a new document.</h4>
                <hr />
                <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="DocumentType"></label>
                    <input asp-for="DocumentType" class="form-control" />

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="DocumentNumber"></label>
                    <input asp-for="DocumentNumber" class="form-control" />

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="DocumentExpiry"></label>
                    <input asp-for="DocumentExpiry" class="form-control" />

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label asp-for="SharedStatus">
                            <input asp-for="SharedStatus" />
                             @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.SharedStatus)
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Upload</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    @section Scripts {
        @await Html.PartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial")
    }
```

Comment: How would it be recognized? Referring to the full namespace is correct, as you've mentioned in your post. You declare the `UploadDocumentViewModel` in namespace `App.Models.DocumentViewModels`, so you have to refer to it either with `@model App.Models.DocumentViewModels.UploadDocumentViewModel` or have a `using App.Models.DocumentViewModels;` in there.

Comment: @nbokmans - Thank you. This is so obvious it is painful! Do you have any idea as to why I don't need to be so specific for the ViewModels in the other namespaces?

Comment: @Corey what do you mean in other namespaces? Please give us an example of which one you do not need to be specific about.

Comment: @Corey make sure they have a `namespace` declaration in them.